# Can I make a "push" from Subversion to a GitHub repository?

Tags: git, svn, github, version-control, vb6

I'm using SVN (subversion) with Visual Basic 6.0 source files, I have my local repository (with all the stuff: solutions, code, etc, etc). But I wonder if..

> Could I do -*something like in Git*- a **push** to a Remote Repository?

Imagine that I have:

```
    1. My Repository in GitHub, 
    2. My local repository,
    And I do some changes in the local repository, changes that 
    I want to send to the remote repository...
```

With Git it will be something like

```
git add "name of the file"
git commit -m "Commit message"
git push  branchname
```

*I'm doing this so quickly, so, excuse me if I'm missing something.*

---

> **Is it possible do this but with SVN** for Visual Basic 6.0 code?

Push to a GitHub's remote repository?

Thanks for your attention, any comment, or advice is welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Github repositories can also be accessed from svn clients, see https://github.com/blog/1178-collaborating-on-github-with-subversion